# How to remove Programatically properties configured in Persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JBOSS seam with Hibernate as the JPA provider.

In my Persistence.xml

```
   <properties>
            <!-- Basic -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"        value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"   value="com.wi.test.audit.ActivityInterceptor"/>
    </properties>
```

In Components.xml

```
<persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="mydb" />
    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" />
    <transaction:entity-transaction entity-manager="#{entityManager}" />
    <factory
        name="session" 
        scope="STATELESS" 
        auto-create="true" 
        value="#{entityManager.delegate}"
    />
```

Now In my program i want to remove the interceptor that i have configured by removing the property hibernate.ejb.interceptor.

I have tried getting properties map,removing the interceptor property and creating a new entitymanager.But it is still using the interceptor configured before.

code i am using to remove the interceptor

```
Field f = SessionFactoryImpl.class.getDeclaredField("properties");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Properties p = (Properties)f.get(session.getSessionFactory());
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>((Map) p);
        map.remove("hibernate.ejb.interceptor");
        localSession =(Session)entityFactory.createEntityManager(map).getDelegate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Hibernate version are you using?

It is not enough to just remove the property, you have to remove the initialized interceptor from the Hibernate directly - also through reflection API. On sessionFactory is field sessionFactoryOptions, which contains the reference to the instance, so you could try to remove that.

EDIT: Actually you could try to replace it with EmptyInterceptor, because null will not work (you would get nullPointer on flush)

This solution is meant for global usage. For local usage, you have to replace the interceptor on your current session (can be retrieved from entityManager).